# View pushed off screen by Grid / List View

Tags: java, android, user-interface, view

I already did some research on that question, found some topic but nothing that helped me.

This is what I have :

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <GridView
      android:id="@+id/grid"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:numColumns="2"
      android:padding="5dp"/>

    <EditText
      android:id="@+id/edit"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:padding="5dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem I have is that when there are too many elements in my grid, the edittext is pushed off the screen. I tried to use alignParentBottom on the editText but this is not what I want.

I was wondering if there is any way to keep the edit text always visible even if there are many elements in the grid view AND to keep the edit text below the grid and not aligned bottom with the parent. 
I also tried to use a scroll view instead of the relative layout... but this is wrong too cause there are too many bugs using a grid view inside a scroll view.

I hope that I'm clear, don't hesitate to ask for more information.

Thanks you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with a simple `LinearLayout` too:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/grid"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:padding="5dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

</LinearLayout>
```

I've experienced `LinearLayout`to be faster and more robust then `RelativeLayout` but that's more kind of personal opnion.

Comment: Thank you very much that's what I was looking for. Actually I didn't know that layout_weight was not working with RelativeLayout. It is working well with LinearLayout.

Comment: you saved my night :D

Answer (score 0):

This should do your job.

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <GridView
      android:id="@+id/grid"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:numColumns="2"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="8"
      android:padding="5dp"/>

    <EditText
      android:id="@+id/edit"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_below="@+id/grid"
      android:layout_weight="2"
      android:padding="5dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```